# How to write a jsp code to accept order from stationary shop and display and to include list of items user can choose and order

Tags: java, jsp

Am a beginner in jsp and I've tried code in java.
Here's my code in java

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
class ListDemo extends JFrame implements ListSelectionListener {
    Container cp;
    JList jlist;
    JLabel lblPrice;
    String[] prod = {
        “Pen”,
        ”Pencil”,
        ”Ruler”,
        ”Eraser”,
        ”Shapner”
    };
    int[] price = {
        12,
        13,
        15,
        45,
        25
    };
    ListDemo() {
        cp = this.getContentPane();
        cp.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        jlist = new JList(items);
        lblPrice = new JLabel(“”);
        jlist.addListSelectionListener(this);
        cp.add(jlist);
        cp.add(lblPrice);
    }
    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
        if (jlist.getSelectedIndex() == -1) {
            lblPrice.setText(“no items selected”);
        } else {
            int index = jlist.getSelectedIndex();
            lblPrice.setText(“Price: “+price[index]);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        ListDemo lstObj = new ListDemo();
        lstObj.setSize(400, 400);
        lstObj.setVisible(true);
        lstObj.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

In the above code ListSelectionListener is used to react to the change in selection of the value in JList Component.

Help me with JSP code

Comment: This is java  code ? where is your jsp ?

Comment: I need jsp code only.....I hve tried in java

Comment: What you have tried for jsp?

Answer (score 0):

You can below way.

```
 <html>
<head>
<script>
    function callFn(value) {
        alert(value)
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <select onchange="callFn(this.value)">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
    </select>
</body>
</html>
```